# Movie Poster for Linked Data

Tags: semantic-web, movie, linkedmdb

How to display the movie poster using linked data by utilizing **OMDBApi** or **themoviedb.org** (they have JSON). Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your question is a bit broad, can you elaborate on the exact problem you are having trying to use these technologies? Where are you hoping to "display" these movie posters? Or provide your attempted solution as an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the instructions on http://www.omdbapi.com/ -  it can return either a JSON or XML object with the link to the poster you wish to display, it says you need to register for the poster to work but appears to return the image (I've not checked if it displays though). All you need do is pass either a search string like the name, or name and year, or the unique ID from imdb, and it will pass the result or set of results back to you.

Comment: linking to related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151272/given-an-imdb-movie-id-how-do-i-programmatically-get-its-poster-image/28677948#28677948